# How do I rotate a ball which sits on 4 other balls sitting on motors tilted over the y axis?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image: project]Basically I have this watch winder design. The big ball on top has watches in it and sits on the 4 smaller balls, each of which sits on top of its own roller in the base. What orientation do the smaller ones have to be rotating in order for the larger ball to spin on a tilt. I need each rotation to be slightly more to one side than the next almost like it's spiraling, and will eventually move back to the home position.
Thanks.

Comment: I think we need a picture.